# Applying Quicken Spell-Like Ability to Alternate Form (Sp)

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Quicken Spell-Like Ability feat says

> Using a quickened spell-like ability is a swift action...
>
> In addition, a spell-like ability that duplicates a spell with a casting time greater than 1 full round cannot be quickened.

However there are spell-like abilities that do not copy any spells but take multiple rounds like Alternate Form. In the case of a spell-like ability not duplicating a spell but taking multiple rounds can the spell-like ability be quickened?

Comment: *Monster Manual* [alternate form](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#alternate-form) is typically a supernatural ability, so the feat Quicken Spell-like Ability won't apply. (The exception is the yuan-ti that have a spell-like version of alternate form, which is weird and untouched by errata and the premium edition, but even that ability says it functions like *polymorph* hence it takes a standard action.) Can you be more specific about which creature has an nonstandard spell-like ability that also lacks a level but takes longer than a 1 full round to use?

Comment: There is also song dragons alternate form ability which is listed as spell-like ability.

Comment: I'll ask the same thing differently. Even if it is spell-like, why do you think Alternate Form takes more than a full round to use? It may be irrelevant from the question's body, but title suggests you are interested in Alternate Form's mechanic specifically if not only.

Comment: Is there a song dragon that's different from the one in *Monsters of Faerûn*? That song dragon's alternate for is listed as a supernatural ability.

Answer (score 2):

A spell-like ability takes 1 standard action to use, unless it mimics a spell with a different casting time, or is otherwise specified in the creature's description. Such a spell can have a *duration* longer than one round, but you can still quicken it as long as the *casting time* isn't longer than one round.

In the SRD, under "Actions In Combat", using a spell-like ability is listed in the table for Standard Actions. Additionally, the section on spell-like abilities states:

> A spell-like ability takes the same amount of time to complete as the spell that it mimics (usually 1 standard action) unless otherwise stated.

Note that the song dragon's Alternate Form is a supernatural (Su) ability, not spell-like (Sp), and would thus not qualify for Quicken Spell-Like Ability.